# Difference between the use of "supplier", "vendor", "provider"

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns, synonyms, agent-nouns

Which is the difference between the use of *supplier, vendor, provider*? The way I see it, they are complete synonyms. Am I right?

Answer (score 6):

A supplier might not be paid for what he has supplied.  A vendor, one who sales, must certainly expect to be paid.  And a provider, much like a supplier, might not be paid perhaps, like many health care providers, receive payment from a source other than the person whom he provides a service.  All that said, in the appropriate context all three of the words could be synonyms.
I am not sure there are many "complete synonyms."  If words are completely synonymous wouldn't all but one devolve out of the language?  But maybe that's just an understanding I got from Mr. Darwin.

Answer (score 2):

It is often a matter of context, for example,

*providing* for your family,
wholesale *supplying* goods for the store
software *vendor* selling services to

*supplying* food for your family sounds ankward.